# Deploy Symfony 4 project on shared OVH server

Tags: php, apache, deployment, server, symfony4

I would like to deploy my Symfony project in production on shared OVH server but it's not possible to define the APP_ENV environment variable on this type of server.

I get this error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: APP_ENV environment variable is not defined. You need to define environment variables for configuration or add "symfony/dotenv" as a Composer dependency to load variables from a .env file. in /home/ovhpseudo/www/nameofsite/public/index.php:13 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/ovhpseudo/www/nameofsite/public/index.php on line 13

Is it possible to circumvent this without changing offer ? 
Do we have to use this environment variable?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can set environment variables in a `.env` file. Have you tried that? See [the docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dotenv.html).

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with this tutorial : https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony-fundamentals/env-vars-tricks-production .

> composer remove symfony/dotenv

and

> composer require symfony/dotenv

have solved my problem